# Regex string replace in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, regex

Is there a simple way to do the following in mysql:

```
"Value ( some stuff here) " --> "Value"
```

Something similar to `REPLACE("(*)","")`? How would I go about doing this and stripping the remaining whitespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql you cannot replace items of rows with regexp help. So you have to select all values "Value ( some stuff here) " from a defined column. Process them on a client-side with python facilities. After that you need update all rows in a mysql database.

Or you can read this answers [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"/s*/(.*/)/s*"
```

This will match leading whitespace, the text in parenthesis and trailing whitespace.

Look at UDFs(user defined functions).  You'll want something like oracle's REGEXP_REPLACE

Comment: MySQL don't supports regexp

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it about find & replace function in mysql